# How to extract first date and last date in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can some please help me. I wanted to extract first date and last date from the same record also to count(*) number of dates filled and days difference from last date (first date), excluding zero dates. The sample table and desired output are given below:

```
Table1
-----------
id  date1      date2       date3        date4         
1  01/09/2020  02/09/2020  03/09/2020   05/09/2020    
2  02/09/2020  03/09/2020  00/00/0000   05/09/2020      
3  04/08/2020  00/00/0000  06/09/2020   00/00/0000 
4  11/09/2020  00/00/0000  00/00/0000   14/09/2020    
5  00/00/0000  02/09/2020  03/09/2020  00/00/0000     



Desired result
----------------------

id  count(*) first_date   Last_date   days_difference (last-first)
1    4        01/09/2020   05/09/2020  4
2    3        02/09/2020   05/09/2020  3 
3    2        04/08/2020   06/08/2020  2
4    2        11/09/2020   14/09/2020  3
5    2        02/09/2020   03/09/2020  1
```

Thank you in advance.

```html
correct syntax:

After inputs from many experts, here is correct syntax: 

select id, count(ndate) as  count, min(ndate) as first_date, max(ndate) as last_date, DATEDIFF(MAX(ndate), MIN(ndate)) `days_difference` from (
select id, ndate from (select id, date1 as ndate from table1
UNION ALL
select id, date2 as ndate from table1
UNION ALL
select id, date3 as ndate from table1
UNION ALL
select id, date4 as ndate from table1) a where ndate!='0000-00-00') as b group by id;
```

Comment: First fix your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be reasonably confident that your data model is catastrophically flawed.

Comment: Hi, This is a sample table.

Comment: The argument still applies, otherwise you end up with the horrors described by Akina below.

Comment: *This is a sample table* Nevertheless it tells that your data is storing in not normal form.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thank you. Could you please advise how to fix the schema, if this is the scenario.

Comment: I thought I did already !?!

Answer (score 1):

<s>```
SELECT id, 
       (date1 IS NOT NULL) + (date2 IS NOT NULL) + (date3 IS NOT NULL) + (date4 IS NOT NULL) `count(*)`,
       LEAST(date1, date2, date3, date4) first_date,
       GREATEST(date1, date2, date3, date4) last_date,
       DATEDIFF(GREATEST(date1, date2, date3, date4), LEAST(date1, date2, date3, date4)) `days_difference (last-first)`
FROM table1
```</s>

```
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(date1) `count(*)`,
       MIN(date1) first_date,
       MAX(date1) last_date,
       DATEDIFF(MAX(date1), MIN(date1)) `days_difference (last-first)`
FROM ( SELECT id, date1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, date2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, date3
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, date4 ) subquery
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Hi Akina, Thanks very much. I tried this  code but the following  error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ date2 IS NOT NULL + date3 IS NOT NULL + date4 IS NOT NULL `count(*)`, L' at line 2

Comment: @awan If so wrap each separate subexpression with parenthesis. I'll edit shortly... done.

Comment: Ok but how to exclude null values from first_date. It is showing null in the first_date column. I wanted to exclude the null values. Also the  days_difference output is not correct.

Comment: Least() starts from null values

Comment: @awan That's true, I forget about it. If so the best way is to normalize your data (but you may do this in the subquery using UNION ALL until altering the scheme). Edited.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the edited query but it gives the result same as previous. Same error- null values in first_date

Comment: @awan *Same error- null values in first_date* I don't believe, `MIN()` ignores NULL values. `MIN()` returns NULL only when ALL values are NULL - but in this case `MAX()` will return NULL too.

Comment: I have edited little bit in your syntax and it is working fine. Please see the edits in my first post. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @awan Zero date and NULL date are diffferent things. And you do not need in separate subquery level for eliminating zero dates - according WHERE may be placed immediately before GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes. That's true. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A normalised environment might look somewhat as follows:

```
id* date_ref* date      
 1         1  2020/09/01
 2         1  2020/09/02
 3         1  2020/08/04
 4         1  2020/09/11
 
 1         2  2020/09/02
 2         2  2020/09/03
 5         2  2020/09/02
 
 1         3  2020/09/03
 3         3  2020/09/06
 5         3  2020/09/03
 
 1         4  2020/09/05
 2         4  2020/09/05
 4         4  2020/09/14

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

From here, queries against the data set become trivial (and even elegant)

Comment: Thanks. That's a great help. Appreciated